# Global state reseting local state in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, state

I have both global redux state state object, and a local one, for handling ui stuff in the component.

The problem is that changes to the redux state reset my local/component state.

Is there any way to prevent that?

My code

```
// component
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        location:5,
    }

onOtherLocationChange(text) {
    this.props.otherLocationChanged(text);
}

// in render
// the location is set to the correct value, and button is selected on click
<Button active={this.state.location === 6 ? true : false}
    onPress={() => this.setState({ location: 6 })}> // updating the local state
    <Text>LOCATION 6</Text>
</Button>
<Button active={this.state.location === 5 ? true : false}
    onPress={() => this.setState({ location: 5 })}> // updating the local state
    <Text>LOCATION 5</Text>
</Button>
<Button
    last active={this.state.location === 7 ? true : false} // updating the local state
        onPress={() => this.setState({ location: 7 })} >
    <Text>LOCATION 7</Text>
</Button>

 // text input that changes value in global state
 // this text input is displayed, but writing anything resets state back to 5
 if(this.state.location == 7) {
        return (
            <Item stackedLabel>
                <Label>Adresa mjesta rada</Label>
                <Input value={this.props.other_location} onChangeText={this.onOtherLocationChange.bind(this)} />
            </Item>
        )
    }
```

Writing in the text input triggers the update of the redux state

```
// reducer, there is no location prop in the initial state object
...
case JOB_OTHER_LOCATION_CHANGED:
        // after this location resets back to 5
        return { ...state, other_location: action.payload, error: '' };
 default:
        return state;
```

Action creator:

```
export const otherLocationChanged = (text) => {
    return {
       type: JOB_OTHER_LOCATION_CHANGED,
       payload: text
    };
};
```

Comment: Your redux state should not be effecting your local state. Please post your `onOtherLocationChange` function. Either something is happening there, or I would also check to see if your component is unmounting and remounting for some reason

Comment: I would add `componentWillUnmount() {console.log('unmount')}` and see what happens. If I had to guess I'd say thats the issue.

Comment: In your reducer do you have a `default` case that return `state`? We need more code to debug this. If you can, post all reducer, component and action contents.

Comment: I've added the default option in reducer, onOtherLocationChange action creator and event handler in the component.I've also added componentWillUnmount and it didnt log anything when changing the location values

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that setState() function was being called at the end of componentDidUpdate()

I added a check to see if desired props were updated before calling that setState.